What is The Best way to trace image to carve inside geometry nodes
I tried several ways to trace image inside geometry nodes , I knew that I can trace image with grease pencil , but I need a way to update image coordinate instantly inside GeoNodes , my result came out with round corners , straight line came wavy
I tried to sample color attribute around points to attract this points position to detected  black edges of the image , but I failed

This is My Result



i tried to upload blender file after I posted this post but i faild

i want sharp corners straight lines

I think there isn't a ready solution in GN for that. In Python there surely are tracing libraries. In GN it could be implemented but perhaps it would be quite slow. I have some ideas for it, basically you would take the image, take a grid with high resolution, delete one color (works only on monochromatic images then), separate boundary edges, use a repeat zone to iterate mesh islands, convert to curve, use inner repeat zone to iterate over the paths, detect change on an angle averaged on a ~5-10 points, then mark that as a corner, then smooth everything without moving the corners...

..or it could be easier, if  you can intervene in your pipeline somewhere, to arrange a route to .svg, and import that

Built-in solution will be there in future, see: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/121897
